# mysql PHP auto increment column

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

How do i add an auto incrementing column called ID to these statements:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$username." (uid varchar(255), tweet varchar(255))";
$alter = "ALTER TABLE ".$username." ADD UNIQUE (uid)";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$username." (id MEDIUMINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, uid varchar(255) UNIQUE, tweet varchar(255))";
```

Comment: Why limiting the auto increment to 8 millions?

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$username." (ID int not null auto_increment primary key, uid varchar(255), tweet varchar(255))";
```